# SSR (Express) Angular 9 - Uncaught ReferenceError: $localize is not defined

Tags: express, internationalization, angular9

After having upgrading to Angular 9 i am facing the error : Uncaught ReferenceError: $localize is not defined
Error: It looks like your application or one of its dependencies is using i18n.
Angular 9 introduced a global `$localize()` function that needs to be loaded.
Please run `ng add @angular/localize` from the Angular CLI.
(For non-CLI projects, add `import '@angular/localize/init';` to your `polyfills.ts` file.
For server-side rendering applications add the import to your `main.server.ts` file.)

My app is SSR (Server Side Rendered) and i cant get ride of this message even after following the guidance.

- I serve my files with Express
- I have put : import
  '@angular/localize/init'; in polyfill.ts
- I also ran ng add
  @angular/localize
- I only have a server.js file for Express and i have
  put also import '@angular/localize/init'; in it.

Here is my angular.json file :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "tableng": {
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "en-US",
        "locales": {
          "fr": {
            "translation": "src/translate/messages.fr.xlf",
            "baseHref": "/fr/"
          }
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/tableng",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.css",
              "node_modules/@fullcalendar/resource-timeline/main.css",
              "node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css",
              "node_modules/@fullcalendar/timeline/main.css",
              "src/assets/sb-admin-2.min.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/morestyles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"

            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "fr": {
              "localize": ["fr"]
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "src/ngsw-config.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "tableng:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "fr": {
              "browserTarget": "tableng:build:fr"
            },
            "production": {
              "serve:dist": "http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/tableng",
              "browserTarget": "ng build --prod --localize --build-optimizer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }}
```

and my server.js file :

```
'use strict';
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const $localize = require('@angular/localize');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var directory = '/' + (process.env.STATIC_DIR)

app.use(express.static(__dirname + directory));
app.use('/fr',function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/tableng/fr/index.html');

}); 

app.use('/',function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/tableng/en-US/index.html'); 
}); 

app.use(express.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true})); // to support URL-encoded bodies

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('express - Listening on', port);

});
```

Thanks for any inputs !!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i put this :

```
import '../node_modules/@angular/localize/init';
```

in polyfill, replacing this :

```
import '@angular/localize/init';
```

and its ok !

Comment: that could mean that it was just missing in your `package.json`.

Answer (score 16):

Angular 9 introduced a global `$localize()` function that needs to be loaded.

Please run `ng add @angular/localize` from the Angular CLI.

(For non-CLI projects, add `import '@angular/localize/init';` to your polyfills.ts file)

for more info : https://angular.io/guide/migration-localize